Issue with Pressed Keys from Enhanced Input Actions on Unreal Engine 5.3
I am trying to create a game on unreal engine 5.3 where you have a wizard character. the goal and objective is to press the letter e to have the character go fishing on the pond. I am have been using files and blueprints and game modes from CG Spectrum game kit to make it easier to create the game since it already has characters that can move and jump. I tried adding an action event in the blueprint class I am choosing to spawn under a chosen game mode in the world settings, but when I press play and press the letter e to have the character perform the fishing action, nothing happens. I am having a hard time trying to find the problem to fix it, but I am out of ideas. would you know how to solve it?[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/YFpWiHwx.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/4atPsNNL.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/bZGkDMHU.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/1CiqY93L.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/mLUr8kFD.png)
I tried adding input actione events, I tried going to projects settings/input and add input action mapping. Not sure what else to do.
